# Recursively create a new line break after nth character for a given block of text

Tags: python, recursion, line-breaks

I've written a small script that creates a new line break after a certain character limit has been reached. Now the  problem is that the script outputs the text starting at the end of the text. I can't seem to figure out how to make the text print out in the correct order without making the script more complicated. I'm doing this an exercise to better understand recursion.

**Here is the code:**

```
def insertNewlines(text, lineLength):

    if len(text) <= lineLength:
        return text
    else:
        return insertNewlines(text[lineLength:], lineLength) + '\n' + text[:lineLength]
```

**Here is the test output for a lineLength of 15:**

```
length.  
e desired line   
s or exceeds th  
ord that reache  
n' after each w  
e character  '\  
Insert a newlin  
ewriter would.   
e text as a typ  
length, wrap th  
a desired line   
Given text and
```

**The actual input:**

```
text = "Given text and a desired line length, wrap the text as a typewriter would. Insert a newline character  '\\n' after each word that reaches or exceeds the desired line length."
```

EDIT:
Modified the code based on the suggestion below so that it wraps the words correctly:

```
    if len(text) <= lineLength:
    return text
elif text[lineLength] != ' ':
    return insertNewlines(text[:], lineLength + 1)
else:
    return text[:lineLength] + '\n' + insertNewlines(text[lineLength + 1:], lineLength)
```

**Here is the new output:**
Given text and a
desired line length,
wrap the text as a typewriter
would. Insert a newline character
 '\n' after each word that reaches
or exceeds the desired line length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the order of recursive call. It should be at the tail of the function to achieve what you want. Try this:

```
def insertNewlines(text, lineLength):

    if len(text) <= lineLength:
        return text
    else:
        return text[:lineLength] + '\n' + insertNewlines(text[lineLength:], lineLength)

text = "Given text and a desired line length, wrap the text as a typewriter would. Insert a newline character  '\\n' after each word that reaches or exceeds the desired line length."
print insertNewlines(text, 15)
```

Output:

```
Given text and 
a desired line 
length, wrap th
e text as a typ
ewriter would. 
Insert a newlin
e character  '\
n' after each w
ord that reache
s or exceeds th
e desired line 
length.
```

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you! I have been racking my brain for days now.

Comment: I modified my code so that it wrappes the word correctly based on your suggestion:     if len(text) <= lineLength:
        return text
    elif text[lineLength] != ' ':
        return insertNewlines(text[:], lineLength + 1)
    else:
        return text[:lineLength] + '\n' + insertNewlines(text[lineLength + 1:], lineLength)

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want the words to be cut off at your max width, try the `textwrap` library, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html

```
from textwrap import TextWrapper

text = "Given text and a desired line length, wrap the text as a typewriter would. Insert a newline character  '\\n' after each word that reaches or exceeds the desired line length."

tw = TextWrapper()
tw.width = 20

print "\n".join(tw.wrap(text))
```

**[out]:**

```
Given text and a
desired line length,
wrap the text as a
typewriter would.
Insert a newline
character  '\n'
after each word that
reaches or exceeds
the desired line
length.
```

Here's a native python implementation:

```
text = "Given text and a desired line length, wrap the text as a typewriter would. Insert a newline character  '\\n' after each word that reaches or exceeds the desired line length."

def wrap(txt, width):
    tmp = ""
    for i in txt.split():
        if len(tmp) + len(i) < width:
            tmp+=" "+i
        else:
            print tmp.strip()
            tmp = i

wrap(text, 20)
```

a more pythonic `yield`ing method:

```
def wrap(txt, width):
    tmp = ""
    for i in txt.split():
        if len(tmp) + len(i) < width:
            tmp+=" "+i
        else:
            yield tmp.strip()
            tmp = i

print "\n".join(i for i in wrap(text, 20))
```

Comment: +1 for not splitting single words, though may not be exactly what the OP asks for.